# Get the IP of a server through powershell when it doesnt respond to a ping

Tags: powershell, ping

Due to firewall constraints, the servers I deal with do not reply to a ping, but do give their IP address

for eg, if I do :

```
ping myhost.com
```

I get

```
Pinging myhost.com [192.1.1.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Request Timed Out.
```

How can I just get the IP of the server from powershell? I know it can be done various ways if a server responds to a ping (Test-Connection or Ping-Host) , but I cant figure it when it ignores ping requests

Comment: can you use `nslookup` ?

Comment: Not unless it can run in powershell. This is running from a windows machine and if im not mistaken nslookup is a unix only tool.

Comment: `nslookup` is available in windows command line and powershell, too. Refering to the answers there seems to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can execute nslookup on windows from powershell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) method.
This method will return an array of [System.Net.IPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx) objects.

Examples of usage:

```
$ipAddresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('google.com')
```

List all addresses:

```
$ipAddresses | %{$_.IPAddressToString}
```

Grab the first address in the array:

```
$ipAddresses[0].IPAddressToString
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and resolve it by DNS:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName('google.com').AddressList
```