# Powershell get IPs from hosts programmatically

Tags: powershell, ip, host

I have a list of hosts from my LAN (over 1000) that was extracted in Excel format from previous guy that worked here before I started my employment. I need to know the IP's of each host.

I would need some automatic extract (I hope there should be a smarter method than to ping manually all hosts in order to get the IP). I came across SO and read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808161/get-the-ip-of-a-server-through-powershell-when-it-doesnt-respond-to-a-ping). Using PowerShell means a good step toward automation of what I need.

However, at what I am stuck is how to automate this command (in PowerShell) in order to use the excel file as input (or text) and provide an output file that contains the relevant IPs?

Update: a code I have in mind:

```
$servers = get-content "C:\scr\Servers.txt"
foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    $Addresses = $null
    try {
        $Addresses =     [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$Server").IPAddressToString
    }
    catch { 
        $Addresses = "Server IP cannot resolve."

    }
    foreach($Address in $addresses) {
        write-host $Server, $Address 
    }
}
```

The Excel file used as input contains line by line the hostnames in a single column. This Excel file could be easily converted to text format (which is what I already done by now, resulting the Servers.txt file).

The problem with this code is that it displays the output only in the Powershell window, no file.

Comment: What data about the computers is contained in the Excel file?

Comment: Can you give a sample of your own code? SO is not a script writing service. People here are usually happy to help but own effort is required (since we're not here to do your paid job for you). One tip : de .NET class System.Net.Dns contains multiple methods to resolve hostnames to IP addresses.

Comment: Shall I add something like >C:\pathtooutput.txt somewhere in the code? Where?

Answer (score 1):

```
        $output = @()
        $servers = get-content "C:\scr\Servers.txt"
        foreach ($Server in $Servers)
        {
            $Addresses = $null
            try {
                $Addresses = ((Test-Connection $Server | select -skip 3).IPV4Address).IPAddressToString
            }
            catch { 
                $Addresses = "Server IP cannot resolve."

            }

           $output += New-object psobject -property @{
                      servername = $server
                      Addresses = $Addresses
                      }
     }

        $output | select servername, Addresses | export-csv ".\Addresslist.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, no error, but missing the essential info in the output file, i.e. the IP. Sample from outputfile: STARTING OUTPUTFILE HERE "hostename0","Server IP cannot resolve."
"hostname1","Server IP cannot resolve."
"hostname2",
"hostname3","Server IP cannot resolve."
"hostname4",
"hostname5", ENDING OUTPUTFILE HERE
and so on.

Comment: Running, not yet finished, but an error occurs for several hosts: "Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'xyz' failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found". I am unsure how to get rid of this, also do not know if for the rest of hosts the info is accurate and if will be registered in the output file. No, it was not registered anything It was finished.\

Comment: The same output (no IPs). Errors were those mentioned in the previous comment (error messages are only displayed, not in the output). However, I am positive the solution is closed, so I vote this answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this code has worked successfuly, after tweakening (and also displays in the Powershell windows its outcome - those IPs - during script's execution). At the end, the results are exported in the Addresslist.csv file.

```
    $output = @()
    $servers = get-content "C:\scr\Servers.txt"
    foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
        $Addresses = $null
        try {


            $Addresses =     [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$Server") 
        }
        catch { 
            $Addresses = "Server IP cannot resolve."

        }

       $output += New-object psobject -property @{
                  servername = $server

                  Addresses = $Address


                  }

        foreach($Address in $addresses) {
        write-host $Server, $Address 
                                        }


 }

    $output | select servername, Addresses | export-csv ".\Addresslist.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```